# Django/SQL double entry table for template

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I have the following models in my django app:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Vote(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

For a given Poll, I need to display in the template a double-entry table like the following, listing all Users who have voted in this Poll and placing an 'x' for each Choice that the user has voted:

```
       [choice1] [choice2] [choice3]
[user1]                        x
[user2]    x                   x
[user3]              x          
[user4]              x         x
```

1. What would be the optimal way to implement this using the django ORM in order to minimize the database hits when populating the table?
2. Which object should be passed to the template in the context variable, in order conduct the logic in the view instead of the template?

The queries I know:

```
# get all votes for the given Poll (pk)
votes = Vote.objects.filter(choice__poll__pk=pk)
# get all users that has voted
usernames = votes.values('user__username')
# get the choices for the Poll
choices = Poll.objects.get(pk=pk).choice_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the following:

```
# yourapp/models.py
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField

class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @cached_property
    def choices(self):
        return self.choice_set.order_by('id')

    @cached_property
    def users_choices(self):
        users = User.objects.filter(vote__choice__poll=self)

        for choice  in self.choices:
            users = users.annotate(
                **{str(choice.id): Case(When(vote__choice_id=choice.id, then=True), output_field=BooleanField())}
            )

        return users
```

For example in PostgreSQL users qs converted in such sql query:

```
SELECT
  "yourapp_user"."id",
  "yourapp_user"."username",
  CASE WHEN "yourapp_vote"."choice_id" = 1
    THEN TRUE
  ELSE NULL END AS "1",
  CASE WHEN "yourapp_vote"."choice_id" = 2
    THEN TRUE
  ELSE NULL END AS "2",
  CASE WHEN "yourapp_vote"."choice_id" = 3
    THEN TRUE
  ELSE NULL END AS "3"
FROM "yourapp_user"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_vote" ON ("yourapp_user"."id" = "yourapp_vote"."user_id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "yourapp_choice" ON ("yourapp_vote"."choice_id" = "yourapp_choice"."id")
WHERE "yourapp_choice"."poll_id" = 1
```

View and template can look like this (you don't even need to pass context to template, everything will be taken from Poll model attributes):

```
# yourapp/views.py
class PollDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'user_choices.html'


# yourapp/templates/user_choices.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}{% load customtags %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ poll.title }}</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>username</th>
            {% for choice in poll.choices %}<th>choice{{ choice.id }}</th>{% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for user_choice in poll.users_choices %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user_choice.username }}</td>
            {% for choice in poll.choices %}
                <td>{% if user_choice|get_attr:choice.id %}+{% endif %}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

I had to add custom template filter to get attr by choice id (propably there is more elegant solution which i missed):

```
# yourapp/templatetags/customtags.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='get_attr')
def get_attr(obj, attr_name):
    return getattr(obj, str(attr_name), None)
```